# Download wheel from PyPi

Tags: curl, wget, pypi, python-wheel

How can I download a specific wheel from a package listed on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)? I'm assuming I would use `wget` or `curl`, but I'm not sure of which arguments to use.

Answer (score 11):

PyPI is known to be hard to introspect. Fortunately, the Debian project is used to scan FTP directories for new versions, and set up a solution to workaround this. It is documented at https://wiki.debian.org/debian/watch#PyPI

For exemple, if you access https://pypi.debian.net/pip/, you will have in long list of release. And as you wish, you can directly download a tarball without knowing its checksum, using curl:

```
$ curl -LO https://pypi.debian.net/pip/pip-18.1.tar.gz
```

Note that, even if it's not listed, you can download the wheel. But you may need to construct the URL.

```
$ curl -LO https://pypi.debian.net/pip/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

If you find some tricks around this solution, feel free to share it !

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48327216/2641187

Comment: Worked for my example: `wget https://pypi.debian.net/selenium/selenium-4.5.0-py3-none-any.whl`, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Update 2021: PyPI package pages have a section `#files` where you can conveniently download the .whl you'd like

```
https://pypi.org/project/<package-name>/#files
```

Comment: But there's no direct way to access the .whl link, right?  In other words, I must scrape the .whl URL from the page link you provided above, correct?

Comment: I guess not, as there is no rule how you supply your package, i.e. as whl, egg or just setup code. So you need to check what is actually available for your distro and python version. Ther IS a standard naming convention though https://peps.python.org/pep-0423/