# Where does pip download .whl files?

Tags: python

I'd like to install a certain python package with pip but because of the proxy I am sitting behind pip cannot connect to the internet.

So my question is: Where does pip look for .whl files in order to download them? Can't I just use my browser (which can connect to the internet just fine) to download the .whl file? [Installing the package with the downloaded .whl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file) would be not a problem then.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi

Comment: Why not just configure your proxy?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's the proxy of our company network which takes username and password. I've managed to configure it in the past with set HTTP_PROXY="username:password@proxy..." in the windows shell but for some reason this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @elzell: `pip --proxy username:password@proxy... install ...` should work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unfortunately it doesn't. I guess it's the proxy because only some of the software on my computer which can make an internet connection (e.g. for updates) works when I set the proxy settings correctly - also Firefox only works when I set "Detect proxy settings automatically". That's why I didn't want to struggle with it anymore and look for an easier way.

Comment: Why not ask your IT department how to configure the proxy? Pip supports most proxy scenarios, it’s just another HTTPS client.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure I will do this, but that means opening a ticket and waiting some days or weeks before I get a reply, so I had hoped for the expertise of Stackoverflow to get a quick solution.

Comment: More relevant today now that pip doesn't work in python < 2.7.9

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`pip` searches the [Python package index (PyPI)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), each package lists downloads (including wheels, if there are any) with a direct download link on the page. Package pages have the form of `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/<package_name>` or `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/<package_name>/<version>` for specific versions.

If you can only download wheels manually with your browser, it doesn't matter where you put the wheel file. Just install the wheel file directly:

```
pip install path/to/wheel.whl
```

However, `pip` supports downloading over a proxy just fine:

```
pip --proxy username:password@proxy_server:proxy_port install ...
```

See the [`--proxy` command line switch documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/cmdoption-proxy). You can add the proxy setting to a [`pip` configuration file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration) so you don't have to set it on the command line each time, or by setting environment variables; see the [*Using a Proxy Server* section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server) in the Pip User Guide.

Comment: In 2021 this answer is only relevant to Python 2.7.9+

Comment: @JonathanRys: in what way? Python 2.7.9 is hardly relevant any more, or are you saying this doesn't apply to Python 3.x? I can assure you that my answer is as relevant today as it was 3 years ago.

Comment: Your comment is relevant today to supported versions of Python, but this is no longer true for Python < 2.7.9 because PyPi has dropped non-SNI support across the board.  That means pip and get-pip no longer work there.

Comment: @JonathanRys yes, or rather, Fastly, the CDN provider, is dropping support and so PyPI must follow. I’ve kept a few backports to older Python releases going for a while but even if you can’t migrate away from Python 2 at this point, you should not ever be using anything less than Python 2.7.9+ for several other reasons, not least due to security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 9):

How to get an URL pip is using to download the file:

- Get JSON from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/package_name/json
- parse releases part, select the latest release
- go through available files (usually there are more than one), taking your platform into account (e.g. x32 vs x64, Windows or Linux version, installed Python etc)
- use `url` property

E.g.:

```
import requests
package = requests.get("https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/json").json()
max_ver = max(package["releases"].keys())
# ... check compatibility
file = get_file_idx(package['releases'][max_ver])
urllib.urlretrieve(file["url"])
```

Comment: Showing the `requests` path is all very well, but rather pointless when the OP is having issues configuring a proxy, don't you think? A *human* would just go to the package page, not the JSON URL.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand this is not the answer to the original question, but I imagine this snippet might come in handy in a similar situation